# NSString doesn't overwrites with a new value

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios7

Trying to remove all the urls from text:

```
- (NSString *)cleanText:(NSString *)text{
    NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it.";
    NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
    NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
            NSString *matchingString = [match description];
            NSLog(@"found URL: %@", matchingString);
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:matchingString withString:@""];
        }
    }
    NSLog(string);
    return string;
}
```

However `string` returns unchanged (there is match).

**Upd.:** Console output:

```
found URL: <NSLinkCheckingResult: 0xb2b03f0>{22, 36}{http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA}
2013-10-02 20:19:52.772 
This is a sample of a http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA sentence with a URL within it and a number 097843.
```

*Ready working recipe done by @Raphael Schweikert.*

Comment: just tried it.works for me. I know you believe there is a match but could you post the log of matchingString?

Comment: @abhineetprasad Thanks for info. I'll update post with output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `[match description]` does not return the matching string; it returns a string that looks like this:

```
"<NSLinkCheckingResult: 0x8cd5150>{22,36}{http://abc.com/efg.php?EFAei687e3EsA}"
```

To replace the matched URL in your string, you should do:

```
string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:match.range withString:@""];
```

Comment: I believe this won’t work when there are multiple matches as the range indices won’t be correct for subsequent replacements. The matches should first be sorted by descending start index.

Comment: Yes, that's correct - I was just showing why his example wasn't working, and what the correct way to replace a match would be. The rest is left as an exercise for the reader. ;-)

Comment: @Shmidt To sort the matches correctly, use `matches = [matches sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSTextCheckingResult *match1, NSTextCheckingResult *match2) {return match1.range.location > match2.range.location ? NSOrderedAscending : NSOrderedDescending;}];`.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert I did it a little bit another way, please see updated post.

Comment: @Shmidt I’ve added my own answer because I think what you’re doing is a bit of an overkill as the whole string has to be searched multiple times…

Answer (score 1):

According to [Apple’s own Douglas Davidson](http://osdir.com/ml/general/2012-08/msg26115.html), the matches are guaranteed to be in the order they appear in the string. So instead of sorting the `matches` array (as [I suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/28311512?noredirect=1)), it can just be iterated in reverse.

The whole code sample would then look as follows:

```
NSString *string = @"This is a sample of a http://abc.com/efg.php sentence (http://abc.com/efg.php) with a URL within it and some more text afterwards so there is no index error.";
NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:0|NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in [matches reverseObjectEnumerator]) {
    string = [string stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:match.range withString:@""];
}
```

The check for `match.resultType == NSTextCheckingTypeLink` can be omitted as you’ve already specified in the options that you’re only interested in links.